# Accessing HSQLDB "res" database bundled as resource in jar is extremely slow

Tags: java, maven, hsqldb

I'm attempting to build an open source [project](https://github.com/timmolter/Datasets) to provide easy access to machine learning datasets, which bundles the data in an easily accessible way. Basically, I have code, which converts the raw data into a `HSQLDB` `file` DB, producing `*.data`, `*.properties`, and `*.script` files. I then take those 3 files, put them in `src/main/resources` of my `Maven` project and build a jar. Applications depending on this jar can then access the `HSQLDB` database as a `res` database.

Technically, I have no problems getting all the pieces in place to accomplish this. However, accessing the data is extremely slow. The strange thing is though, that if I have the datasets project and a project depending on datasets both open in Eclipse and run it from there, it's fast as one would expect. This means that the problem has to do with the `HSQLDB` files being jarred up. Another clue, is that the larger the DB, the (seemingly) exponentially longer it takes to access the data.

I've tried bumping of the memory and perm space given as JVM args. I've also tried setting various `HSQLDB` flags in the the `*.properties` file as well.

Any ideas??

Edit: I also have jar compression turned off using the `<compress>false</compress>` element in the maven-jar-plugin definition.

Comment: Jars are compressed. I assume the slowness is due to the overhead of accessing files from within a Jar via the `ClassLoader`. Lots of libraries (including [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/performance-tuning.html)) recommend copying resources to a file system location. Maybe move your resources to `java.io.temp`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have jar compression turned off using the `<compress>false</compress>` element in the `maven-jar-plugin` definition. It makes no difference whether it's compressed or not. Still, your idea is worth trying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things including setting the cache size and cache rows as suggested at the `HSQLDB` [forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73674/topic/8689376/index/page/1). I ended up solving this problem with a workaround as suggested above by [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider), which was to:

1. Create a temporary dir at `java.io.temp`.
2. Move the DB files out of the jar and into the temporary dir.
3. Use the `file` `HSQLDB` database using these files.
4. Cleanup afterwards by deleting the temporary dir.

Worked like a charm. A bit of a hack, but at least it works.